# Does earth have chakras as well?

Tags: scripture, earth, chakras

I read in an article somewhere that as our body have 7 major Chakras, so does the Earth. Energy flows through each of Earth’s main Chakra and makes up the spiritual body that is our world.

My question: Is this fact stated anywhere in our scriptures? If yes, where are these centers? Please do cite authentic references in your answer.

Comment: Read my answer again https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4093/why-do-we-see-lord-shiva-under-the-feet-of-mother-kali/34542#34542 7 Chakras are planets both inside and outside, every living being has them, Earth is one of 7 Chakras. Sun is Sahasrara, Moon is Agya, Mars(Tuesday) is Vishudda, Mercury(Wednesday) is Anahata, Jupiter(Thursday) is Manipur, Venus-Earth(Friday) are Swadhistana  and Saturn(Saturday) is Muladhara etc., parallel to the order of 7 days of week. Hence, it written in Bible also, God created world in 6days & rested on 7th which is Sabbath or Sunday holiday worldwide.

Comment: In my opinion this is one of the fantastic questions. Bravo.